# C# not able to upload file

Tags: c#

I am trying to upload a file using the below source code, but its not working. Is anyone have any suggestion?

```
<div class="panel">
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadResumes", "Employee", new { 
enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-hand"></i>
</div>

<h4>Welcome @Model.FullName!</h4>
<p>@ViewBag.Error</p>
<div class="form-group bootstrap-fileinput-style-01">
    <label>Upload Resume</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" required="required" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:265px" accept="application/msword,text/plain, application/pdf">
    <span class="font12 font-italic">** File must not bigger than 2MB</span>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="name" class="btn btn-primary" value="UploadResumes" />
}

</div>
```

Comment: Can you out define `not working`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to update as below and see if this works.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadResumes", "Employee",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

}
```